# Using NSWindow or NSPanel as "CardLayout"

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cardlayout

How guys.
I'm not top dev in java, but what I`m really not is cocoa top dev :P

I would like to have your assistance to produce a layout with cocoa and IB to work just like the CardLayout in Java.

Do you have some idea of how to do it?
Thanks for the attention!

EDIT:
CardLayout: A set of panels ("cards") are designed to compose a "deck of cards".It works like a queue of panels, in which only  the first "card" is shown on the interface.I can easily interchange between cards if I want so to modify the interface to the user.

I hope I could help you to help me. =)

Comment: Can you post a description of what CardLayout does in Java? A lot of us are not Java programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tabless NSTabView can be used for something like this.